# Pandas : Remove a part of a string before the first white space

Tags: python, pandas

Good morning,
I have a data frame:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Item_Description': ['dfd_landing BKK_AOT-Airbridge / Jetty', 'dfd_month DEL_Updater Services Pvt Ltd-Office Cleaning'])
```

I would like to remove everything before the first space so the result would be:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Item_Description': ['BKK_AOT-Airbridge / Jetty', 'DEL_Updater Services Pvt Ltd-Office Cleaning'])
```

I tried with :

```
    df1['Item_Description'] = df1['Item_Description'].str.replace(".*(" ")", "")
```

but it removes everything.

Is there any way to do it in one line?

Kind regards

Comment: added a solution with regex, one liner. does it help?

Answer (score 3):

You can also `split` and `join` without `apply`:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Item_Description': ['dfd_landing BKK_AOT-Airbridge / Jetty', 'dfd_month DEL_Updater Services Pvt Ltd-Office Cleaning']})

df1['Item_Description'] = df1['Item_Description'].str.split().str[1:].str.join(' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine a `split()` and a `' 'join()` to accomplish this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Item_Description': ['dfd_landing BKK_AOT-Airbridge / Jetty', 'dfd_month DEL_Updater Services Pvt Ltd-Office Cleaning']})
df1['Item_Description'] = df1['Item_Description'].apply(lambda x : ' '.join(x.split(' ')[1:]))
df1
```

Comment: Yes either way would work you are correct! I'll keep my answer and you can add one if you would like so they have ALL the options haha

Answer (score 0):

here is another way to do it using regex

```
df1['item'] = df1['Item_Description'].str.extract(r'\s(.*)')
df1
```

```
    Item_Description                                    item
0   dfd_landing BKK_AOT-Airbridge / Jetty               BKK_AOT-Airbridge / Jetty
1   dfd_month DEL_Updater Services Pvt Ltd-Office ...   DEL_Updater Services Pvt Ltd-Office Cleaning
```